# Illegal zero-sized array

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, есть такой класс:

```
template<typename T>
class DynamicArray
{
public:
    DynamicArray(int size);
    ~DynamicArray(void);
    void Add(T element); 
    T Get(int index);
    void Resize(int newSize);
    //void Show();
private:
    T* _box[];
    int _currentSize;
    int _currentPosition;
};

template<typename T>
DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray(int size) {
    _box = new T[size];
    _currentSize = size;
    _currentPosition = 0;
}

template<typename T>
DynamicArray<T>::~DynamicArray(void) {
    delete[] _box;
}
```

Но почему-то в строчке

```
T* _box[]
```

показывает такую ошибку:

```
error C2229: class 'DynamicArray<T>' has an illegal zero-sized array
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй в определении класса изменить...

```
T* _box[];
```

на

```
T* _box;
```

Answer (score 7):

По всей видимости, в вашем случае проблема в простой синтаксической ошибке. Но раз уж спросили почему, добавлю пояснение.

```
T* _box[];
```

Это объявление определяет буфер `_box` указателей на `T` неопределенного размера, причем содержимое этого массива есть часть вашей структуры.
В таком случае говорят о структурах переменного размера. При выделении памяти под такую структуру размер буфера `_box` определяется следующим образом:

```
bufferSize = (bytesAllocated - sizeof(DynamicArray<T>)) / sizeof(T)
```

- (`bytesAllocated` - размер блока памяти, выделенного под структуру)

Очевидно, что если после такого буфера объявлены еще какие-то члены, то их смещение в структуре определить невозможно. Поэтому структура может содержать не более одного буфера неопределенного размера и только в конце. Вы объявляете после буфера еще 2 члена ( `_currentSize` и `_currentPosition`), поэтому и получаете ошибку.